# Buttons with input radio types inserted

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to create html buttons with input radio type inserted into the buttons. When one clicks the buttons the input radio type is checked. I used this code but whenever I click the button the input radio button isn't checked. How do I make it work?:

```
<button class="button">
<input type="radio" name="input" id="choice-1"  value="0">Chlorophyll
</button>

document.querySelector('.button').addEventListener('click', function(){
document.querySelector('#choice-1').checked;
});
```

Comment: Does it have to be a button element? If not, you could achieve the same thing with some CSS and a label without the need for any JS.

Comment: Your html is invalid, the [`<button>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) element may contain "*[phrasing] content but there must be no Interactive content.*"

Answer (score 3):

## [Interactive Elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element#Interactive_elements)

An interactive element within an interactive element will no longer function as an interactive element.

### HTML

The following demo uses a `<label>` as a button synced to a `<input type="checkbox">` by using the **[for attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes#Attribute_list)** and the `<input>` `#id` as it's value.

### JavaScript

The details are commented in the demo below, the following list provides references concerning the JavaScript in the demo:

- [**HTMLFormControlsCollection**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection)
- **[Event Delegation](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/handling_events_for_many_elements.htm)**
- **[Event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)**
- **[Event.currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)**

-

---

### Demo

**Details commented in demo**

```js
// Reference the <form>
var ui = document.forms['ui'];

// Register change event on <form>
ui.addEventListener('change', chx);

function chx(e) {

  // Reference <output>
  var out = ui.out;
  // Reference clicked element
  var tgt = e.target;
  // if clicked element is NOT element registered to event
  if (tgt !== e.currentTarget) {
    // Set <output> to display the #id and value of checked
    out.value = `ID: ${tgt.id} | Value: ${tgt.value}`;
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  font: 700 small-caps 16px/1.5 Consolas;
}

form * {
  font: inherit
}

label {
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1px 5px;
  color: gold;
  border: 3px ridge gold;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 110px;
}

[type=radio] {
  transform: translateY(2.5px);
}

#out {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<form id='ui'>

  <label for='rad0'>Radio 1&nbsp;
    <input id='rad0' name='rad' type='radio' value='0'>
  </label>

  <label for='rad1'>Radio 2&nbsp;
    <input id='rad1' name='rad' type='radio' value='1'>
  </label>

  <label for='rad2'>Radio 3&nbsp;
    <input id='rad2' name='rad' type='radio' value='2'>
  </label><br><br>

  <output id='out'></output>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do `document.querySelector('#choice-1').checked = true;` as `.checked` needs to assign with a boolean value.

```js
document.querySelector('.button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('#choice-1').checked = true;
});
```

```html
<button class="button">
<input type="radio" name="input" id="choice-1" value="0">Chlorophyll
</button>
```

Comment: @Antik Agarwal. Thanks so much. It worked just as how I needed it.

Comment: @Benjamin glad to help. You can tick mark the answer if it was helpful to you.